# function with parameter in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I can not do a function with an input parameter and use it. I did what we see below, but it does not work :(

the problem is that I manage to recover matricule and date. But I can not send matricule in getUnCollaborateur in my home.ts and therefore receive it in the function getUnCollaborateur to use it to recover from json

**home.html**

```
<ion-content>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Matricule</ion-label>
      <ion-input placeholder="ex: a131" [(ngModel)]="matricule"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary">Date d'embauche</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime placeholder=" ex: 1992/12/11" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="date"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button full (tap)="connexion()">CONNEXION</button>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

  collaborateur: ApiGsbGlobal = new ApiGsbGlobal;

  matricule: string;
  date: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private apiGsbService: ApiGsbService) {
  }

  private connexion(){
    this.apiGsbService.getUnCollaborateurs(this.matricule)
    .then(collaborateurFetched => {
      this.collaborateur = collaborateurFetched;
      console.log(this.matricule);
      console.log(this.collaborateur.COL_DATEEMBAUCHE);
      console.log(this.date);
      if(this.matricule != null && this.collaborateur.COL_DATEEMBAUCHE == this.date){
        this.navCtrl.push(MenuPage);
      }
    })
  }
}
```

**apiGsb.service.ts**

```
public getUnCollaborateurs(id): Promise<any> {
    const url = `${this.baseUrl}apiGSB/collaborateur/read_one.php?id=${id}`;

    return this.http.get(url)
    .toPromise()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(error => console.log('Une erreur est survenue ' + error))
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, post the actual code

Comment: It's same, it's the actual code

Comment: Please read the FAQs. Pictures of code are bad. Actual posted code is good.

Comment: The reason to post the actual code is...people can (quickly) cut-and-paste it into their examples when helping you.  Whereas, they cannot do so with a pic.  As such, it is considered polite.  Happy coding :-)

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand the issue, the problem is that id is null when you enter in the method getUnCollaborateurs, isn't it? which is the value of matricule when you hit this line `this.apiGsbService.getUnCollaborateurs(this.matricule)` ? Can you please include your html code?